# Injecting properties into WSPasswordCallback for JBossWS CXF moduel

Tags: java, web-services, spring, cxf, jboss7.x

I'm having a problem with webservice authentication (WS-Security) while converting an existing application that executes in JBoss 4.3 to JBoss 7.

I'm following information on: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/JBoss+Web+Services+Documentation and it seems to be working for WS-Security authentication.

The web application contains a jbossws-cxf.xml file and JBoss 7 has spring module installed correctly. The endpoint is configured with the following XML:

```
<beans xmlns='http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:beans='http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans'
xmlns:jaxws='http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws'
xsi:schemaLocation='http://cxf.apache.org/core
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd'>

<!-- WS-Security -->
<bean id="webServicePasswordCallBack" class="ie.one23.general.security.WebServicePasswordCallback">
    <property name="WS_USERNAME" value="${properties.ws-credentials.username}" />
    <property name="WS_PASSWORD" value="${properties.ws-credentials.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="SMSServiceLoggingCXFIncomingInterceptor" class="ie.one23.general.logging.LoggingCXFIncomingInterceptor" />

<!-- Web Service endpoint -->
<!-- See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/Apache+CXF+integration -->
<jaxws:endpoint id="SMSService" implementor="ie.one23.commonservices.webservice.controller.SMSWebServiceImpl" address="/SMSService/SMSService">

    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <!-- WS-Security -->
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor" />
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                    <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                    <entry key="passwordCallbackRef">
                        <ref bean="webServicePasswordCallBack" />
                    </entry>
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>

    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>

</jaxws:endpoint>

</beans>
```

The problem here is that the properties WS_USERNAME and WS_PASSWORD are being injected in the bean with the actual text ${properties.ws-credentials.username} and ${properties.ws-credentials.password}, respectively, instead of the actual value that comes from a properties file and that is loaded using the following XML (in a separate Spring configuration XML file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

<!-- ================================================================== -->

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:/${jboss.server.config.dir}/props/sms-service-credentials.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- ================================================================== -->

</beans>
```

It's as if the properties file is being loaded only after the properties have been injected in the bean....

Has anyone come across this issue and knows how to solve it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the tutorial here (http://codingbone.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/how-to-load-properties-files-into-spring-and-expose-to-the-java-classes/) and now instead of injecting the properties into WSPAsswordCallback bean I get them at runtime using PropertiesUtil class.

```
public class PropertiesUtil extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

private static Map<String, Object> propertiesMap;

@Override
protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, Properties props) throws BeansException {
    super.processProperties(beanFactory, props);

    propertiesMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (Object key : props.keySet()) {
        String keyStr = key.toString();
        propertiesMap.put(keyStr, resolvePlaceholder(keyStr, props));
    }
}

public static Object getProperty(String name) {
    return propertiesMap.get(name);
}
}
```